# pandas reading CSV data formatted with comma for thousands separator

Tags: pandas, csv, separator

I am trying to create a dataframe in pandas using a CSV that is semicolon-delimited, and uses commas for the thousands separator on numeric data. Is there a way to read this in so that the type of the column is float and not string?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Pass param `thousands=','` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) to read those values as thousands:

```
In [27]:
import pandas as pd
import io

t="""id;value
0;123,123
1;221,323,330
2;32,001"""
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), thousands=r',', sep=';')

Out[27]:
   id      value
0   0     123123
1   1  221323330
2   2      32001
```

Comment: What does the `r` stand for, in the `thousands` field?

Comment: @kotchwane the `r` makes it a [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/13138364) (and is not actually necessary in this case)

Answer (score 10):

The answer to this question should be short:

```
df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv', thousands=',')
```

Comment: with ; separator df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=";", thousands=',')

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation there is a keyword argument 'thousands' that you can pass the ',' into. Likewise if you had European data containing a '.' for the separator you could do the same.