# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas

I know this post cant be replicated as the data is in a CSV format that I am reading locally, but I could post the data to a github account if it would be useful. I am attempting to find correlation first:

```
ng = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/me/Desktop/ngDataBaseline.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
ng.head()
```

Which will return two columns:

```
    HDD Therm
Date        
2011-05-01  347 3,506
2011-06-01  74  1,237
2011-07-01  0   139
2011-08-01  0   35
2011-09-01  154 170
```

But if I do a:
`ng['HDD'].corr(ng['Therm'])`

I get an error about `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`

Which doesnt make sense to me as it should all be pandas series i think.

If I do a `print(type(ng['HDD']))` Ipython will output `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

As the same with `print(type(ng['Therm']))` so why cant I correlate the data?

Comment: 'Therm' is a string. look at the commas in the column.

Comment: 'Therm' column was read in as string not float (because it contains commas). If you had done `ng.info()` you would have seen that. There are many duplicates of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that because of the commas, the `Therm` column is being read as a string. Luckily, `read_csv` has a `decimal` argument to deal with that. Use:

```
ng = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/me/Desktop/ngDataBaseline.csv', decimal=',', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

>>> ng
         Date  HDD    Therm
0  2011-05-01  347    3.506
1  2011-06-01   74    1.237
2  2011-07-01    0  139.000
3  2011-08-01    0   35.000
4  2011-09-01  154  170.000
```

Then, your `corr` works:

```
>>> ng['HDD'].corr(ng['Therm'])
-0.275450033528333
```

If instead, the comma is a thousands delimiter, use the argument `thousands`:

```
ng = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/me/Desktop/ngDataBaseline.csv', thousands=',', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

>>> ng
         Date  HDD  Therm
0  2011-05-01  347   3506
1  2011-06-01   74   1237
2  2011-07-01    0    139
3  2011-08-01    0     35
4  2011-09-01  154    170

>>> ng['HDD'].corr(ng['Therm'])
0.8794452911190037
```

Comment: Wow `pray hands emoji`, thank you so much. The `thousands=','` is exactly what I needed...

Comment: Please don't answer a question which is [known to be a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439933/pandas-reading-csv-data-formatted-with-comma-for-thousands-separator). It will get closed and you won't earn any rep.