# dataframe column value sum showing wrongly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have the value placed in the data frame.

```py
abc = data
abc = pd.DataFrame(abc)

total = abc['profit'].sum()
print(total)

output of print(abc['profit'])

0     -720.00
1    2,620.00
Name: m2m, dtype: object

total = abc['profit'].sum()
print(total)
```

The output is showing like this:
`-720.002,620.00`

I want value should be the sum and provide one output.

looking for help,

Comment: you have to convert to numerical values first.

Comment: use the `thousands` argument in `pd.read_csv` `from io import StringIO`; `d = """0     -720.00
1    2,620.00
"""`;`df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),sep='\s+',header=None,thousands=',')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas reading CSV data formatted with comma for thousands separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439933/pandas-reading-csv-data-formatted-with-comma-for-thousands-separator)

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` is defined as concatenation for strings.  Convert to `float` and you get what you expect.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"profit":["-720.00","2,620.00"]})

print(df["profit"].sum())
print(df["profit"].str.replace(",","").astype(float).sum())
```

### output

```
-720.002,620.00
1900.0
```