# Using .sort_values() in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I am trying to figure out how to sort a dataframe base on the values of a column.

At the moment, it is re-organising the dataframe order, but not in order of smallest -> largest or largest -> smallest. It seems to be a random order.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like the column values are str, not numeric. Note there are commas.

Comment: Please, show [mre]. Don't post images of code, error, data. Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas reading CSV data formatted with comma for thousands separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439933/pandas-reading-csv-data-formatted-with-comma-for-thousands-separator)

Comment: Read the CSV using the `dtype` param (of `read_csv`) as `dtype={'Impressions': int}`. Then, sort will work naturally / as expected.

Comment: @S3DEV, without `thousands=','` this will raise `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Comment: @buran - Ah yes.  Then both could be used (?) to read the data in properly from source, rather than having to fix it later.

Comment: @S3DEV, I **guess** their file uses comma as both separator and thousands separator and some values are quoted. Just supplying `thousands` should work and it will infer the type correctly. But it may be necessary to pass `sep` and/or `quoting`. Of course it does not hurt to also explicitly specify `dtype`. If OP has given sample data we can be more certain.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Impressions` column is stored as a string rather than as an int. So, it's sorting the digit representations in "alphabetical" order.

One solution is to change the values to `int` within the data frame. Another is to use a `key` for the `sort_values` call that converts the string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

The second option that @BenGrossmann said looks like this:

`data.sort_values(by='Impressions', key=lambda col: int(col.replace(",","")))`

Comment: OP should read the data using `thousands` param of `read_csv` See the dup.

Comment: yeah that's not a bad idea at all.

Comment: Or, read the CSV using the `dtype` param (of `read_csv`) as `dtype={'Impressions': int}`. Then, sort will work naturally without the need for a `lambda` hack.

Comment: @S3DEV, without `thousands=','` this will raise `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`